# SSL errors with Couchdb on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, couchdb

I am beginning to set up CouchDB on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server (yes, it expires next year) and I'm having troubles setting up SSL connections. For the moment, I don't have any CA signed certs for it, so I've been following the steps on the CouchDB [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html#secure-socket-level-options). To list my changes to the config file: I have essentially kept them as the default except I set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 to be accessible over the network, and I moved my database_dir and view_index_dir to another path. For the SSL part, I followed the documentation precisely step-by-step, and restarted the couch service. From localhost, I get the response I expect:

```
user@ubuntu:/etc/couchdb# curl -k https://127.0.0.1:6984/
{"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"43cf4aa1c38ef1feb9ec71ab93dddea3","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"14.04"}}
```

Now, when I try to access the server over the network (which right now is just me accessing a VM from the host, having tried a bridged and host-only adapter in VBox):

```
courtney@host:~$ curl -k https://192.168.10.38:6984/
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 192.168.10.38:6984
```

At this point, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is the documentation inaccurate? Or perhaps some packages I'm missing? I installed couch from the [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~couchdb/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I'm not sure what the cause was, but this was an error that was specific to me using doing TLS and couch in a VM. I spun up a VPS and tried it there and the problem was completely gone.